Standard error of RMSE and differences in RMSE
I have a set of models $M = \{1, ..., m, ..., K\}$, and for each I am calculating RMSE on out-of-sample data as standard:
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{RMSE_{m}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\hat{y} - y)^2}
\end{equation}
I would also like to the present the difference in RMSE. And because the out-of-sample data is just one finite sample of possible data, I'd like an estimate of the standard error of their differences.
Their differences are easy, but I am not sure how best to calculate the standard error of the difference. If I was dealing with the mean squared error (MSE), for a difference between model $k$ and $j$ and where $\mathrm{SE_{j_{i}}}$ is the squared error of the $i$th data point from the $j$th model, I'd do:
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{MSE_{\mathrm{diff_{kj}}}} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} (\mathrm{SE_{k_{i}}} - \mathrm{SE_{j_{i}}})\\
     \mathrm{se(MSE_{\mathrm{diff_{kj}}}}) = \frac{sd(MSE_{\mathrm{diff_{kj}}})}{\sqrt{N}}
\end{equation}
But for RMSE, the above gets tricky with when to apply the square root (to me), and the fact that we can't take the square root of the mean differences if it's negative. Taking the mean of the square roots is also not the same as RMSE, due to the the generalized mean inequality.
Does what I'm trying to do actually exist as we know of RMSE?
